# Naming convention for class of constants in C#: plural or singular?

Tags: c#, coding-style, naming-conventions

The guidelines are clear for enumerations...

> Do use a singular name for an enumeration, unless its values are bit fields.

(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx)

...but not so clear for a class of constants (or read-only static fields/propertes). For example, should the name of this class be singular or plural?

```
public static class Token // or Tokens?
{
    public const string Foo = "Foo";
    public const string Bar = "Bar";
    public const string Doo = "Doo";
    public const string Hicky = "Hicky";
}
```

Comment: Consider this, if you were creating a class to hold extension methods, would you give it a singular or plural name?  Also think about the other methods that simply holds references to specific values/instances.  e.g., `Colors`.

Comment: For what it's worth, Windows itself seems to use the plural: [System.Windows.Media.Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx), [System.Windows.Media.Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen not always though; for example `System.Drawing.Color` takes the opposite approach. -- it seems sometimes the WPF classes do weird things with naming.

Comment: @RaymondChen And also consider [System.Windows.Media.DashStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.dashstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) vs. [System.Windows.Media.DashStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.dashstyles(v=vs.110).aspx). Here, the latter is a predefined set of the former.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would use the plural: `Tokens`.  This implies that the static class is serving as a collection of items of some sort (whose runtime types are not that of the class).

On the other hand, an enumeration's fields *are instances of the enumeration type*.  For example, `TypeCode.String` *is* a `TypeCode`.  It would be weird to say that `TypeCodes.String` is a `TypeCodes`.

However, in your `Tokens` example, using the singular gives us `Token.Foo`, which *is* a token, but it is not a `Token` (it is a `string`).

(Or, if you use the plural class name, `Tokens.Foo` is a `string`, not a `Tokens`.  Ack!)

Comment: +1.  I like the same common-sensical approach to the situation.  When naming anything, I make sure that it is pronouncable and usable in conversation, since there is a good chance that at one point or another, it might need to be communicated to another developer.  While there are "standards" in place in how we name things, there are always exceptional circumstances that may dictate a departure from the norm.

Answer (score 6):

Since both are used essentially the same way, and are conceptually the same thing, I'd recommend just following the enum guidelines.

Comment: +1 for the singular name. IMHO plural makes sense when writing the static class (this is a container with Tokens Foo, Bar, etc), whereas singular makes sense when using the static class (Do something with Token Foo).

Because the 2nd case (using a token) should far outweigh the 1st case (defining tokens), singular is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any official naming standard to link to, but I can tell you what I would do.

I would use the plural name: Tokens

Comment: I should note that I often break the naming guideline for enums also and name them plural.  It just feels more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the plural name: `Tokens`

However you may consider creating a `Token` class for holding the const value.

This would be similar to `System.Windows.Media.Colors` where e.g. `Colors.Blue` returns a `System.Windows.Media.Color` instance.

```
public class Token
{
    public Token(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator string(Token token)
    {
        return token == null ? null : token.Value;
    }

    public bool Equals(string value)
    {
        return String.Equals(Value, value);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Token;
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals(other.Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

public static class Tokens
{
    public static readonly Token Foo = new Token("Foo");
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // You can use it as if they were string constants.
        string token = Tokens.Foo;
        bool areEquals = String.Equals(token, Tokens.Foo);
    }
}
```